# Howto change from standard UIPageViewController code to Segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue

For an app I am creating I started out with a standard Tabbed Application Template. From there I implemented a tutorial for a `UIPageViewController` and all work correctly together. However now I want to start using Segue's as this makes the app better understandable in my opinion. Problem here is I really don't know how to make this work.

The following code is now used to create the viewControllers from the `UIStoryBoard`

```
- (IBAction)goToTables:(id)sender {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    // Create page view controller
    self.weightPageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WeightPageViewController"];
    self.weightPageViewController.dataSource = self;

    WeightPageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.weightPageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:_weightPageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_weightPageViewController.view];
    [self.weightPageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

What I am looking for is the code which can be used to do the same but then in a Segue, as I cannot get to a point where it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard you create a segue between 2 viewControllers, give the segue a name and then call the following:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@" <Segue-Name> " sender:self];
```

there is also a callback:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

which will give you access to the destination viewController to pass data, call functions etc

Comment: Hi @Simon thanks for the input, but my problem is not the Segues themselves, but what to do with all the code in my IBAction. I cannot seem to find out what code to re-use, and what code to ditch (or rewrite in the prepareForSegue callback) from that IBAction.

Comment: @Hugo I'm sorry I really don't understand your comment. The first line handles all the movement between one viewController to another, this is all that is required in the goToTables function to move to the other screen. Then if you need to pass in data, or run a function call on the destination viewController you do so using segue.destinationViewCOntroller in the prepareForSegue callback. The rest is depending on how the logic of your app works, I can't tell you what you do and don't need because I don't know where or how this stuff is being used or even any of the data types.